# Does web sockets only support 1 connection using IIS 8 Client

Tags: websocket, windows-8.1, iis-8

i have a MVC asp.net web app.

It is hosted on my local network on a Windows 8.1 32bit OS.

I have found that SignalR only supports 1 client connection.

So, I removed SignalR and switched to web sockets.

However, this did not solve the problem.

Am I accurate in stating that Web Sockets only supports 1 client connection on this OS and IIS 8 Client?

Is the solution to use IIS Express because I had problems getting this to work and in the end ended up rebuilding my PC.

Is there no workaround for this issue?

This is my code:

In my Global.cs file:

```
public static WebSocketCollection clients = new WebSocketCollection();
```

In my handler:

```
public class MicrosoftWebSockets : WebSocketHandler
{
    private string name;

    public override void OnOpen()
    {

        this.name = this.WebSocketContext.QueryString["chatName"];
        MvcApplication.clients.Add(this);
        //clients.Broadcast(name + " has connected.");
    }
    public void SendImage(byte[] jpeg)
    {
        this.Send(jpeg);
    }
    public override void OnMessage(string message)
    {
        MvcApplication.clients.Broadcast(string.Format("{0} said: {1}", name, message));
    }

    public override void OnClose()
    {
        MvcApplication.clients.Remove(this);
        MvcApplication.clients.Broadcast(string.Format("{0} has gone away.", name));
    }    
}
```

In my HTML page:

```
   var conversation = $('conversation');
    var url = 'ws://192.168.0.13:80/SocketHandler.ashx?name=John Doe';
    ws = new WebSocket(url);
    ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
    ws.onerror = function (e) {
        $('#divSystemMessage').html('Problem with connection: ' + e.message);
    };

    ws.onopen = function () {
        $('#divSystemMessage').html('Client connected');
    };

    ws.onmessage = function (e) {
        liveViewIndex = 0;
        desktopImage.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64ArrayBuffer(e.data);
    };

    ws.onclose = function () {
        $('#divSystemMessage').html('Closed connection!');
    };

    public class SocketHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
                context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new MicrosoftWebSockets());
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably you need to show the relevant client and server code for people to have an idea whether this might be something you're doing in your code.

Comment: Hi, I will have to post the code later as not near PC. But, the code is standard but my main question is whether iis 8 client supports multiple clients. If that is confirmed as negative the it must be my code. I do know multi connections for signalR on iis 8 is not supported

Comment: I am having similar issue of only one websocket working it seems. Did you find a solution? Thanks!

Comment: I  afraid not. If u use different ports for each connecting client it may work. I decided to support 1 client per PC instead so never tried it